Error: validateAndFixActivity(): missing activity type - npm botbuilder-v.4.22.3
We are getting Error: validateAndFixActivity(): missing activity type  for the below code snippet, while trying to update the adapative card details based on message id using contex.updateActivity(message)
package used are
    "@azure/identity": "^4.4.0",
    "@microsoft/adaptivecards-tools": "^1.3.4",
    "@microsoft/teamsfx": "^2.3.2",
    "botbuilder": "^4.22.3",
    "restify": "^10.0.0"

try {
await teamsBot.run(context);
const updatedTemplate = structuredClone(onCallNotificationTemplate);
const card2 = CardFactory.adaptiveCard(
AdaptiveCards.declare\<CardDataOnCall\>(updatedTemplate).render(payload)
 );
console.log("Card2-------------\>: ", card2);
const message = MessageFactory.attachment(card2);
message.id = "xxxxxxxxx";
message.type = "message";

await context.updateActivity(message);

catch (error) {
console.error("Error sending on-call adaptive card:", error);
}

We are attempting to update the card details by calling the API endpoint. It would be incredibly helpful if you could guide us in resolving this issue or share the Node.js API endpoint that allows us to update the card details.
